# How can I share a computer's wired internet with another computer wirelessly?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, network-shares, connection-sharing

I use cable internet (router wired to my PC) and my PC has a wireless network card.

How can I connect my laptop to the PC in order to use the cable internet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Internet Connection Sharing. Go to Network connections on your PC. If you are using 7 or Vista, use the "Setup a new connection or Network" and select "allow others to use this internet connection."

If you are using XP, find the wired connection, RClick and Properties.  Select the **Sharing** tab and click the check box for "allow other network users. . ."  Select the Wireless Connection as your home network connection.